# How to correct the "MissingNo" Minecraft Error on item I gave myself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I gave myself a custom Minecraft tool for adventure mode that can break certain type of block but sometimes it shows **"Can Break: missingno"**. It only appears on some of the blocks. If I give myself the tool that can break dirt it can break dirt, the "missingno" error was found after I typed:

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:[minecraft:andesite]}
```

The command should give me an iron pickaxe that can break andesite but it appears to show the "missingno" text.

Comment: It may help to also include the version of Minecraft you are playing in your post.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Easter_eggs#Pok%C3%A9mon):

> In Java Edition, using commands to obtain an item that can mine a non-existent block ID (any block ID that is not in the game), sets the text to simply display "missingno", likely a reference to the famous glitched pokémon MissingNo. in the Pokémon Red and Blue video games.

Are you sure your command is correct/spelled correctly? The [other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/406196/163757) indicates you're missing double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using the correct block names in your command. As you're trying to give yourself an iron pickaxe that can break andesite. Make sure that "andesite" is spelled correctly and that you're using the correct Minecraft block ID.

Correct command:

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:andesite"]}
```

Comment: It looks like the main difference is you have quotes around `minecraft:andesite` which perhaps that is the reason it doesn't work for the OP (at least in their post they don't have it quoted - but in the game itself is another question - the same can be said for the spelling.)  They did have it working for dirt however, so maybe not?

Comment: Yeah, quotes around "minecraft:andesite" are necessary in Minecraft commands to indicate that it's a string representing the block ID. Without the quotes, Minecraft might interpret it as a variable or something else, leading to the "missingno" error.

Comment: yes the command is spelled correctly but still showed the missingno bug, i even copied your recommended command